# Choose empty spot on x and z axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, unityscript

If I want to spawn objects around a target, do I have to use the magnitude command like:

```
Instantiate (enemy, spawnLocation.magnitude, transform.rotation);
```

(or something like this)

Or do I have to use something else? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Being a Unity3D user, I added the Unity3D tag.

Comment: and I removed the unity tag, to disambiguate from the Unity IoC container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to Instantiate is a Vector3 relating to the position. Magnitude should return a float.

The easiest thing to do is to user Random.Range to get a random number.  Take that number and add it to the X and/or Z of the target's position.

Let me know if you want some example code and I will see what I can do.

Comment: Nah, I dont need an example code, but thanks anyway :) But what I mean is that I want to spawn objects "around" a target, like a circle. 

For example:

A group of enemies gather around the hero to beat the shit oughta him. So they will gang up in a circle around the hero.

Comment: Correct, you should use Random.Range to get a number (say between -5 and 5) then take that number and make it a vector3 (Vector3(NUM, 0, NUM)) then take that Vector3 and add it to the target's position. IE: Instantiate(enemy, target.position + NEWVECTOR3, transform.rotation)